# rendering YUV ffmpeg frames in Android native ndk

Tags: android-ndk, ffmpeg, video-streaming, libyuv

Can we render YUV frames from ffmpeg streaming output(AV_PIX_FMT_YUV420P) directly in Android screen without converting to RGB format?

Comment: Is this question the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26336024/rendering-yuv-format-in-android ?

Comment: @fadden Yes,when i tried rendering YUV directly in screen,i am getting the video display for a second and the application stops,can you help me how to get rid of this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had some experience with Google WebRTC open source project recently.

It provide a fully packaged video call example, also contains an Android demo.

What the demo doing is displaying decoded video frames, which is I420(YUV420P) pixel format.

Take a look at the source code: https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/source/browse/trunk/webrtc/modules/video_render/android/video_render_opengles20.cc

Comment: The above link is useful.Thanks,I am looking some tutorial for the same with OPENGLES1,can you help with it..

Comment: In Google WebRTC demo, for those without ES 2.0, libyuv based YUV -> RGB conversion is used. Which provide many optimization including NEON SIMD version. I also agree with this approach because if ES 2.0 is not available it'd be better rely on CPU rather than GPU.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/source/browse/trunk/src/modules/video_render/main/source/android/video_render_opengles20.cc?r=1988